# Does the sequence of functions converge uniformly?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0,& x<0 \\
nx, &0 \leq x <1/n \\
1, &x \geq 1/n
\end{cases}$$

I suppose the sequence converges pointwise to $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,& x \leq0 \\
1, & x>0\\
\end{cases}$$

And the sequence will not converge uniformly on any domain with $0$ as a limit point. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: You didn’t really give any reasoning, but your statements are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the $f_n$ are continuous and the pointwise limit is not, the convergence cannot be uniform.  To do it from sratch, take $x_n=1/n^2$ and note that $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|=|1/n-1|$